# Running a Python function as a background process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following piece of code that updates as per the value in time.sleep.

```
import time

class Mine:

    def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = 0
        while True:
            self.stock += 1
            print(self.stock)
            time.sleep(1)    

bigmine = Mine(0)
```

As you can see, for each tick of the loop I want an action to happen. The problem is that as expected, the code runs nothing else while this loop is repeating.

How do I make that a background process so that I can then run other commands to reset the stock or display the stock of the mine?

Comment: just use a thread

Comment: take a look at *gevent* too:  http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/

Comment: Using Python`s fairly new Async-Functionality might be an option and an even better solution than using threads (handling the state within the thread (i.e. communicating/synchronizations threads), depending on what exactly you want to achieve. See this [blogpost](https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/) for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this concept of multithreading to achieve this:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = 0
        while True:
            self.stock += 1
            print(self.stock)
            time.sleep(1)    

def func2():
    print 'Foreground code Here!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

For further information click [HERE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/)